# What does Exclamation (!) mark means in path?

Tags: shell, unix

When I run a script that's designed to print the changes that will be done after running another command, I get something like this as output:

```
/<path>/filename!abc.something
```

what does this ! marks means here?

filename is a ear package that contains abc.something file in it.

Comment: There is no standardized meaning for this in UNIX. Exclamation marks are actually valid in filenames -- you could literally have a file named `filename!abc.something` (try running `touch 'filename!abc.something'`), or there could be a meaning specific to your software. Presumably, in this particular case, the "specific to your software" meaning refers to contents of an archive.

Comment: Actually, when I jar -tvf filename, I can see the abc.something file present there. Does this mean, the changes are going to be done in this particular file!

Comment: Again, there is no standardized meaning here.

Comment: Which command in the script generates that output?